# Error while connecting to Database on hosted server

Tags: mysql, server, mysql-connect

> Warning: mysql_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in
>   /home/vol14_1/byethost31.com/b31_16461744/htdocs/Mysql/con.php on line
>   7
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): No such file or directory in
>   /home/vol14_1/byethost31.com/b31_16461744/htdocs/Mysql/con.php on line
>   8
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be
>   established in
>   /home/vol14_1/byethost31.com/b31_16461744/htdocs/Mysql/con.php on line
>   8

I have the below code

```
<?php 
     $localhost="localhost"; 
     $username=b31_16461744; 
     $pass=test123; 
     $dbname=b31_16461744_user; 
     $a= mysqli_connect($localhost,$user,$pass); 
     mysql_select_db($dbname); 
     if($a)
     { 
       echo "connected..";
     } 
     else 
     { 
       echo "not...!!"; 
     }
?>
```

Comment: could you provide your php code `con.php` ?

Comment: @Alex `code`
<?php

$localhost="localhost";
$username=b31_16461744;
$pass=test123;
$dbname=b31_16461744_user;
$a= mysqli_connect($localhost,$user,$pass);
 mysql_select_db($dbname);
 if($a){
     echo "connected..";
     }
     else {
         echo "not...!!";
     }
     
     
?>

Comment: @SUM you're mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` you can't do that.

Comment: and these need to be quoted `$username=b31_16461744; $pass=test123; $dbname=b31_16461744_user;` those are being treated as constants, instead of strings.

Comment: hm...but @Fred-ii- this time i have quoted it....but the same error again...

Comment: @SUM I posted an answer for you below.

Comment: I posted an answer over 20 minutes. If that still does not work for you, then contact your web host, whom I assume is https://byethost.com/ - those credentials should have been sent to you after you successfully signed up. If that is NOT your host, then it's someone else. If my answer solved it, you can accept it in order to mark the question as solved. @SUM - you haven't told me where we are at here.

Comment: @SUM You're not helping me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sidenote:** Assuming the credentials are correct, given to you by your web host.

There are several problems with this code (taken from a comment you left).

Firstly, three of your declarations are not quoted and are being treated as constants.

PHP error reporting would have thrown notices of undefined constants.

These are treated as constants:

```
 $username=b31_16461744; 
 $pass=test123; 
 $dbname=b31_16461744_user;
```

You are also referencing the wrong variable for the username being `$user` which should be `$username`. Error reporting would have signabled an undefined variable notice.

Then you're mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` syntax. Those different MySQL APIs do NOT intermix. You must use the same one throughout your code.

Sidenote: The other question you posted [Access denied for user 'test123'@'192.168.0.38' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32269976/) you are using `sql306.byethost31.com` for the host. Make sure that is correct. I have no idea what settings that host wants you to use.

```
<?php 
     $localhost="localhost"; 
     $username="b31_16461744"; 
     $pass="test123"; 
     $dbname="b31_16461744_user"; 
     $a= mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $pass); 
     mysqli_select_db($a, $dbname); 
     if($a)
     { 
       echo "connected..";
     } 
     else 
     { 
       echo "not...!!"; 
     }
?>
```

or just use all four parameters:

```
<?php 
     $localhost="localhost"; 
     $username="b31_16461744"; 
     $pass="test123"; 
     $dbname="b31_16461744_user"; 
     $a= mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $pass, $dbname); 

     if($a)
     { 
       echo "connected..";
     } 
     else 
     { 
       echo "not...!!" . mysqli_error($a); 
     }
?>
```

However, your `else` with the echo does not help you. Use `mysqli_error()` to get the real error.

I.e.: `or die("Error " . mysqli_error($a));`

Example from the manual

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mydb")
        or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production

Comment: Well Ralph. Are you running training courses for beginners now

Comment: @RiggsFolly I thought Sam was doing that? I guess I've inherited the torch Smokey.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- your recommended links helped me alot...thanks once again

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok..just the last thing .. i am retrieving data from database & it has started an infinite loop & displaying the data all the way... ??? what is it...??

Comment: @SUM it would be best if you were to post a new question along with the code you are now using. Please do not modify your existing question. I will see what I or someone else can do to help.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am not allowed to ask more questions for the time being & iam there is a new issue i want to discuss....what should i do now???

Answer (score 0):

I Think Credentials are not correctly set. See Your connection statement.
For Reference :
While Working On Localhost, We write connection statement as :

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db1=mysql_select_db("DatabaseName",$con);
```

But, While working on server, we need to change the following credential.
   Username and password values are must.

```
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","Username","password");
    $db1=mysql_select_db("DatabaseName",$con);
```

Comment: So you are still using the deprecated **`mysql_`** extension. I hope you realise thay PHP7 does not come with a `mysql_` database extension. You should probably consider this in the future, and for the future of the code you write.