# Access denied for user 'test123'@'192.168.0.38' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, access-denied, mysql-connect, database-connection

I want to run this code on byethost31.com (free hosting site) so i am facing " Access denied for user 'test123'@'192.168.0.38' (using password: NO)" Error on console..

```
<?php
$localhost="*************";
$pass="*************";
$usename="*************";
$dbname="*************";

$s=mysql_connect($localhost,$pass,$username);
$t=mysql_select_db($dbname);


if($s ){
 echo "Mysql_connect is successful. <hr>";
}

if($t ){
 echo "Mysql_select_db is successful.. <hr>"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: get the information from your web host

Comment: i am not getting you please explain..??@Fred-ii-

Comment: you also posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253577/error-while-connecting-to-database-on-hosted-server - login to your control panel and consult the Email you may or should have received from your web host. Contact support also. There isn't much anyone can do here for you. Try using a `mysqli_` or PDO connection instead.

Comment: If that is the actual mysql information you show there, I would strongly recommend removing it and not posting it in public.

Comment: you may also try passing db connection to it `$t=mysql_select_db($dbname, $s);`

Comment: This time using password turned to YES but still that errors @MarmiK

Comment: See Jite's answer below.

Comment: possible exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253577/error-while-connecting-to-database-on-hosted-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) for the `mysql_connect` function, you will see that the params it takes is: `Server`, `Username`, `Password` in that order.  You send your password in as username instead of the other way.

I would recommend that you take a look at `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of using the *deprecated* `mysql_*` api.

Comment: yeah good catch. Let's see if that'll get the OP going. OP might have to use `$t=mysql_select_db($dbname, $s);` too.

Comment: thing is though, OP posted already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253577/error-while-connecting-to-database-on-hosted-server and received an answer with the correct syntax http://stackoverflow.com/a/32255589/ and also stated this [in a comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253577/error-while-connecting-to-database-on-hosted-server#comment52393070_32253577) `$a= mysqli_connect($localhost,$user,$pass);` but... they're mixing APIs in that comment.

Comment: what should i do for now..??? still that error "Access denied for the user....". ??@jite